# Javascript Modules

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. It's a JavaScript module.

```
(function() {

   // Object
   var Cahootsy;

   Cahootsy = {
       hello: function () {
           alert('test');
       },
    };

    (Cahootsy.scope = (function() {
        return this;
     })()).Cahootsy = Cahootsy;

    return Cahootsy;

}).call(this);
```

I don't understand the section:

```
    (Cahootsy.scope = (function() {
        return this;
     })()).Cahootsy = Cahootsy;
```

I think it is creating an object referencing 'this' module and then assigns the Cahootsy variable to a global Cahootsy variable. What I don't understand is why 'this' needs to be assigned to Cahootsy.scope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can break it down a little, like so:

```
var getScope = function() {return this;}
Cahootsy.scope = getScope();
getScope().Cahootsy = Cahootsy;
```

What it does is gets the global scope (usually `window`, but not always). Then it creates a link from `Cahootsy` to the global scope via the object's `scope` property, and a link the other way via the scope's `Cahoosty` property.

The result is that, in a browser, you would get `window.Cahootsy` is the object, and `window.Cahootsy.scope` goes back to the window.

Comment: Why would the module hold a reference to the global scope? Also, why not just do `Cahootsy.scope = window`?

Comment: Because as I mentioned, `window` is not always the global scope. For instance, when JavaScript is being run on Node.JS, there is no browser and therefore no `window`.

Comment: This looks like a hacky way to get the global scope! :)

Comment: True. Just `Cahootsy.scope = this` would have been enough.

Answer (score 3):

`(function() { return this; })()` is a trick to return the global object.

This statement sets `Cahootsy.scope` to the global object (for future use), and also sets the `Cahootsy` property of the globalobject to expose `Cahootsy` to the outside world.